# push the element out of flow without making horizontal scroll using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

I've been using bootstrap framework recently. I'm new to this framework.

so I'm trying to position an image next to some text in landing page. I use grid system of the bootstrap and it work. but when I come to push the image using `position: absolute`, and `left:somePX`, it make horizontal scroll and get out of the body of the page. what should I do to prevent this scrolling. I just want to cut the image and position it as I want.

***Note:*** I've applied so many templates using only CSS with out bootstrap and I never get across on same problem.

thank you

here is my html code:

```css
/* landing */


/*this is the image style*/

.landing {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.landing .right .image {
  position: relative;
}

.landing .right .image .back img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

.landing .right .image .mockups {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 100px;
}


/*this is text style I don't think the problem is here but I put it*/

.landing .left {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.landing .left h1 {
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.landing .left p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.landing .left button {}
```

```html
<div class="landing row">
  <div class="col-md-6 left">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Next generation digital banking</h1>
      <p>Take your financial life online. Your Easybank account<br> will be a one-stop-shop for spending, saving,<br> budgeting, investing, and much more.</p>
      <button class="btn linear" type="button">Request Invite</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 right">
    <div class="image">
      <div class="back">
        <img class="back-image img-fluid" src="images\bg-intro-desktop.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="front">
        <img class="img-fluid mockups" src="images\image-mockups.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add to your body:

```
<style>
     body{
          overflow-x: hidden;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Yep I tried it but doesn't work

Comment: what about using position relative instead of absolute ? they work kinda the same.
edit: your question is still unclear, can you provide an image?